# Prevent Capslock from turning off by itself on input source changes

Tags: macos, keyboard, input-source

I am using two input sources, U.S. and 2-Set Korean. (Capslock is not the one I use for switching)

I've found that Capslock turns off by itself when the current input source is changed to the other, except when the target is Japanese: Capslock is untouched (I don't understand there is exception...).

Only the post from [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8046337) describes the same issue; Unfortunately, There was no useful information other than "This is standard behavior".

Whether this is really the expected behavior or not, *I wonder* that there is any way to disable this seamlessly. This is for rather investigation than "I want to do this".

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want is for Caps lock to remain on when switching from US to Korean and back again?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes exactly

Comment: I have investigated earlier but never found any way to change it.  True it stays on from US to Japanese, but not from Japanese to US, I think.